# Trying to load environment values and running migrations on multiple databases

Tags: php, laravel, command, laravel-artisan

I am trying to load configuration for specific sites and running through a custom command but it would not run.

Here is my code.

```
$sites = Site::all();
foreach ($sites as $site) {
     $this->info("Running migrations on Site: {$site->name}:{$site->id}");
     config([
         'database.'.env('DB_CONNECTION').'.database' => env('DB_DATABASE_'.$site->id),
         'database.'.env('DB_CONNECTION').'.username' => env('DB_USERNAME_'.$site->id),
         'database.'.env('DB_CONNECTION').'.password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_'.$site->id),
     ]);
     Artisan::call("migrate", []);
}
```

My envs are something like this with ID appended on the end

```
DB_DATABASE_1=db1
DB_USERNAME_1=root
DB_PASSWORD_1=
```

I must be doing something wrong. Can anyone help me out please.

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate the tables dynamically by making some changes in your env file like below as I tested this and working for me.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE_1=multidb_1
DB_USERNAME_1=root
DB_PASSWORD_1=

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE_2=multidb_2
DB_USERNAME_2=root
DB_PASSWORD_2=
```

and add multiple database configuration array in your **config/database.php** just change *databasename* *username* and *password* and leave other configuration options as it is.

```
'mysql_1' => [
      'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_1', 'forge'),
      'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_1', 'forge'),
      'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_1', ''),
...

'mysql_2' => [
      'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_2', 'forge'),
      'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_2', 'forge'),
      'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_2', ''),
...
```

and set any of them as default like

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql_1'),
```

you will need to specify additional database configuration option which the laravel look from **config/database.php** while migrating using artisan command.

```
for($i=1; $i<=2; $i++)
{
    Artisan::call('migrate --database=mysql_'.$i.'');
}
```

you can use your way to iterate with your site id